# Best way to reset column in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have column `pulls` in my users table it is integer column and i need to reset the value of that column to `0` 1st day of each month.

**I want to know which is the best option using `jobs` or `schedules` and why?**

Comment: Have you looked over the Laravel documentation? You cant run a scheduled automated job without scheduler.  Look over the documents first and try to implement then if you have issues then post here and we will resolve the issues.

Comment: Doing something one the Nth of every month or at a given time every day, or every X minutes is doing something on a schedule. Jobs are just "doing something" there's no schedule associated with them, you can realistically kick off a job at a scheduled time so I guess the answer here is both?

Comment: @ColinMD have you ever consider trying to understand peoples question before giving your thoughts? I have read laravel documents if it could help me decide which is the best for me i wouldn't bother to ask here and answer comments like yours. to me commands can do jobs work and jobs need commands to run then i can't understand why in the first place we need jobs at all??

Comment: @apokryfos if jobs just doing something without scheduling and schedule can do jobs work by commands even without jobs existence then why do i need jobs? why the answer would be both??

Comment: Most things in Laravel are up to the user to decide the best use case for themselves, they give various ways of doing things and then you decide the best use case.  But in your comparison schedules and jobs are not even comparable.  If you said Events and Jobs then yes, there is comparison.  Commands and Jobs, there is comparison.  We cant always rely on other people doing the work for us, sometimes we have to get out there and find out ourselves.

Comment: To answer your question commands don't need jobs. Jobs are their own entity and Commands are there own entity and both can run without each other or with each other.  Jobs are run by dispatching inside the code base. A command is something that you run on the command line.  Both can be scheduled to fire in the scheduler.

Comment: @ColinMD Thanks, so that means it doesn't matter which I use, both can do what I need right?

Comment: @mafortis Yes you can use either to do what you want.  It really depends on your use case as to what is the best option to use.

Comment: thanks for the help.

Comment: A job is an abstract term. It's just a task that needs to be done. Laravel has some more functionality to them like adding them to a queue, but that's about it. The scheduler on the other hand can execute any given code on a specific schedule, that code can be a job or it can be an artisan command or anything so the answer could be both in that you can have a job called "ResetPullsColumn" and you can call that job using the scheduler but also you could for example call it through a web interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you are asking should you use jobs or schedules? am I right?

If this is your question then I will recommend you to make your concept clear about jobs and schedule. They are not alternatives.

**Jobs**

Jobs can perform jobs/tasks/operation.

**Schedules**

Schedules do nothing but run job.

**How to solve your problem?**

So, to do what you want. At first you need to create a job. You can create a job using `php artisan make:job ResetUserPulls` command where `ResetUserPulls` is the name of the Job class. Now, you need to do your operation inside `handle` method of that job.

Now you can schedule the job in `console/Kernel.php` file's `schedule()` method as bolow:

`$schedule->job(new ResetUserPulls)-> monthlyOn(1');`

For more explanation, see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

Lastly, you have to run a crone job to run the schedules as bellow:

`* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: hi, thanks for the explanation but here is my confusion `Schedules do nothing but run job` i get the purpose of jobs but schedules can do jobs work even without job existence just running the commands, then why do I need to use jobs at all? I can make command in schedules and run it by artisan call in controller with carbon monthly am i right?

Comment: Right, you don't need job to run by scheduler you can even run commands. But, in the last line, you mentioned that `artisan call in controller with carbon monthly`. Who is going to call the controller in that case? Here actually you don't need any controller, just artisan command and schedule will do the things alone.

Comment: Nice to see that you now have better understanding about job and schedule. If my answer have helped you to understand jobs and schedule, don't forget to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do something every minutes / hours / months etc... You need a scheduled task. Typically, executing something on the first day of every month could be done with the `monthly()` or `monthlyOn()` methods of the `\Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule` instance available in your `app/Console/Kernel.php` file.

Since a scheduled task could be a job, a command or even a closure, the answer to your question is probably "you can use a job inside a scheduled task".

If you somehow need to execute this task inside the command line, a command (`php artisan make:command`) is suitable. If you need to execute this job at different places inside your application, then a job (`php artisan make:job`) is probably what you need.

It all depends on your needs. What is needed, wherever you put the logic, is a **scheduled task** (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling) .

Comment: thank you, would you give me a sample of `If you need to execute this job at different places inside your application` ? like what purpose?